# trying to install GCC

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gcc, c

I would like to install gcc compiler by this command
`apt install build-essential`

and after pressing Yes, it asks me to insert some media.

`Media change: please insert the disc labeled

 'Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20200203.1)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]`

and this prompt repeats again and again

What's wrong?

Comment: That will be your install media; edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add a "#" to the start of that line to make it not use the installation media (or if using desktop it can be done via gui tools too).  It's usually a warning though, if you `sudo apt update` you should see other lines that will provide the required packages.  FYI: the date is the date of the ISO of the daily image of your install media; the .1 tells you it was the second daily for that day.

Comment: @Pilot6 the answer above was the way more compact and clear

Comment: Thank you, guys!

Comment: Please do your research before asking so many duplicate questions. Thank you!

Comment: Did I interrupt your mind by writing a repeating question on the forum whose owner or moderator you are not at all? I tried to find, but couldn’t, I’m not an idiot to see the answer to my question and ask the same again. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and put `#` in front of the line with `cdrom`

You need to be coneected to the internet to be able to install `gcc`.